# How to catch keystrokes in C#

Tags: c#, event-handling

I am writing a text editor program that requires events to occur when the user inputs combinations such as Ctrl+S to save, I have provided the code for how I thought it was done below but the event doesn't seem to get triggered. I feel like the error may be due to my inexperience with how event handlers are initialised in C#. Any and all help is appreciated.

Form1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Colied_Text
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_CtrlS(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)      //Save file
        {
            if(e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
            {
                textBox1.Text = "Ctrl+S for save";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Form1.Designer.cs:

```
namespace Colied_Text
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this.textBox1.AcceptsReturn = true;
            this.textBox1.AcceptsTab = true;
            this.textBox1.AllowDrop = true;
            this.textBox1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.textBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(0)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))), ((int)(((byte)(192)))));
            this.textBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Consolas", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            this.textBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Menu;
            this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 10);
            this.textBox1.MaxLength = 100000;
            this.textBox1.Multiline = true;
            this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            this.textBox1.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.Both;
            this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(645, 339);
            this.textBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.textBox1_CtrlS);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(0)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))));
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(669, 361);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "CoTxEd";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
    }
}
```

Comment: @derloopkat i just assigned the function that name to signify what keystroke it will handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set property `KeyPreview` to `true` . the form will receive key events before the event is passed to the control that has focus.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.KeyPreview = true;
}
```